Potential Leaked Secret Security in Nextjs build files
The following files are from the Next.js build server folder:

.next/server/server-reference-manifest.json
{"node":{},"edge":{},"encryptionKey":"PhLVgRXgTBFRMVsHasswumD0/xGssj+0lGhP1i8WwlPrRk="}


.next/server/server-reference-manifest
self.__RSC_SERVER_MANIFEST="{\"node\":{},\"edge\":{},\"encryptionKey\":\"1uPhLVgRXgTBFMVHawmD0/xGj+lGhxxxP1i8ssWwlPrDRk=\"}"



These files contain an encryptionKey that is generated with each build. My code audit team has raised concerns about this being a potential secret leak that could threaten security.
Here’s what I know about the files:
In a Next.js application, the server-reference-manifest.json file is likely used to manage server-side references and configurations, possibly related to data fetching or routing.
My questions are:

Is this really a security threat?
Do I need to take action to hide this key or implement any changes?
If there's a solution to address this, could you please help?
If we can bypass this issue, how should I respond to the security team?

Thank you for your assistance.
Not tried to resolve this issue

Those are Server Action IDs that are auto-generated during build introduced in Nextjs 15.

By default, when a Server Action is created and exported, it creates a public HTTP endpoint and should be treated with the same security assumptions and authorization checks. This means, even if a Server Action or utility function is not imported elsewhere in your code, it’s still a publicly accessible.
To improve security, Next.js has the following built-in features:

Secure action IDs: Next.js creates encrypted, non-deterministic IDs to allow the client to reference and call the Server Action. These IDs are periodically recalculated between builds for enhanced security.
Dead code elimination: Unused Server Actions (referenced by their IDs) are removed from client bundle to avoid public access by third-party.


https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations#security
